# Grafana Errors on Initial Load: Unable to find application file error

Tags: grafana

I'm using Grafana v7.3.3 connected to a PostgreSQL. I have it running in a Kubernetes environment using ISTIO. When initially loading the dashboard, I get the following error:

Unable to find application file
Grafana has likely been updated. Please try reloading the page.

Loading chunk 1 failed...

[image]

when I reload the page, I get the following errors:

[image]

and

"upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure"

After waiting for several minutes and performing multiple refreshes, the dashboard will eventually load. Any recommendations on how to resolve the issue is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

My advice is look at the istio proxy sidecar logs in the pod, if you can get anything useful out of it.  I'd say start close...  port forward the pod then the istio ingress gateway service ... but you will have to add metrics-* to your hosts file ... for localhost